# Compare the quantile against a single number by groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, quantile

I have two data frames: the first one contains the product_id and the cycle time for many orders for this product and the other data frame contains the standard cycle time for each product. What I want to achieve is to see compared to their respective standard cycle time against the distribution of actual cycle time. More specifically, for product A the historical cycle time is:

```
cycletime_for_A <- rnorm(n = 100,mean = 5,sd = 2)

standard_ct_for_A <- 8

percentile_of_a <- ecdf(cycletime_for_A)

percentile_of_a(standard_ct_for_A)
```

then I get the result of 0.95, which implies that for 95% of the chance, actual cycle time is shorter than standard cycle time.

However, I have thousands of different products with different standard cycle time, how would I accomplish the same thing with groups? I am aiming for a tidyverse approach if possible.

A minimal example dataset is as below:

```
product_cycle_time <- data.frame(
  product_id = rep(c("A","B","C"),100),
  cycle_time = round(runif(n = 300,min = 1,max = 100))
)

standard_cycle_time <- data.frame(
  product_id=c("A","B","C"),
  std_cycle_time=c(10,20,15)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Basic idea: Split the df's by product id, then use map2 to do the calculation for each product.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(42)

product_cycle_time <- data.frame(
  product_id = rep(c("A","B","C"),100),
  cycle_time = round(runif(n = 300,min = 1,max = 100))
) %>% 
  split(.$product_id)

standard_cycle_time <- data.frame(
  product_id=c("A","B","C"),
  std_cycle_time=c(10,20,15)
)%>% 
  split(.$product_id)

purrr::map2(product_cycle_time, standard_cycle_time, ~ ecdf(.x$cycle_time)(.y$std_cycle_time))
#> $A
#> [1] 0.1
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 0.19
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 0.15
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @stefan for your help and quick response and it works as expected. Really need to spend more time learning about purrr. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could first `merge` the to data frames for more convenience,

```
dat <- merge(product_cycle_time, standard_cycle_time, all=TRUE)
```

then, using `mapply`:

```
with(dat, mapply(function(x, y) ecdf(x)(y), split(cycle_time, product_id), 
                 unique(std_cycle_time)))
#    A    B    C 
# 0.10 0.19 0.15
```

If you want a list rather than a vector use `Map` instead of `mapply`.

*Or*, using `by`:

```
by(dat, dat$product_id, function(x) ecdf(x$cycle_time)(el(x$std_cycle_time)))
# dat$product_id: A
# [1] 0.1
# ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# dat$product_id: B
# [1] 0.19
# ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# dat$product_id: C
# [1] 0.15
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
product_cycle_time <- data.frame(
  product_id=LETTERS[1:3],
  cycle_time=round(runif(300,1,100))
)
standard_cycle_time <- data.frame(
  product_id=LETTERS[1:3],
  std_cycle_time=c(10,20,15)
)
```